# WFE server UPDATE REQUIRED

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-server

I just noticed that one of the two web front end is showing "UPDATE REQUIRED"

I looked it up and it talks about taking several steps to upgrade if the update status under "Upgrade and Migration" is failed..... all the status shows "Succeeded" pic shown below for both

So my question is do i need to do something about this  "UPDATE REQUIRED" status for the web server since everything under "check upgrade status" as shown above

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the installation of a SharePoint-Update, you must trigger the process of a database upgrade. Looks like this was skipped for Server WEB1.

Please run `SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard`on the server or alternatively you can use the CLI-Tool `psconfig` instead. Open PowerShell and execute the following command:

`PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd secureresources -cmd services -install`

Reference: [Why I prefer PSCONFIGUI.EXE over PSCONFIG.EXE](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2015/08/20/why-i-prefer-psconfigui-exe-over-psconfig-exe/)

Answer (score -2):

You may haven't run PSconfig after patching , you can manually run SharePoint configuration wizard as administrator or perform PowerShell command :

```
PSCONFIG -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait
```

Comment: Please note that your PSCONFIG command does not execute all operations that might be necessary for a successful update. As we do not exactly know which update was installed, this might break stuff.